# PHP registration form post method not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make registraton form with oops.But post method and javascript function not working. click on register button nothing happened.
I have used dbconnect.php class for database connecton. and register.php class for insert data.

index.php file:

```
<html>  
 <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getdata()
        {
            var name = document.login.name.value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if(name=="" || email=="" || password="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter data");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
            <center>
                <form name="login" method="post" action="variable.php" onsubmit="return getdata()">
                    Name:      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
                    Email:     <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
                    Password:  <input type="password" name="password" id="passowrd"><br><br> 
                    <input type="button" name="register" value="Register"></input>
                </form>
            </center>
    </body>  
</html>
```

dbconnect.php file:

```
class dbconnect{

     public function __construct()
     {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost:5050","root","");
         if(!con)
         {
             die("Cannot connect database....");
         }
         mysql_select_db("zenbiz",$con) or die("Error: database not found");
     }
 }
```

variable.php file:

```
include_once('register.php');

$obj = new register();
if($_POST['register'])
{
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $register = $obj->userRegister($username,$email,$password);
    if($register)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Registration successfull....')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Not Registered.....')</script>";
    }
}
```

register.php file:

```
include_once('dbconnect.php');
    class register{

        public function __construct()
        {
            $db = new dbconnect();
        }

        public function userRegister($name,$email,$password)
        {
                $query = "INSERT INTO users(username,emailid,password) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$password."')";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Help would be appreciaed. Thank you.

Comment: you need a oncick="getdata()" on your button to call the function.

Comment: `<input type="button"` does not submit a form! Use `<input type="submit"`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's